# How do you convert a String into an array of bytes using a customized table for the letters to be converted into bytes to be written by BinaryWriter?

Tags: vb.net

I have no idea of how to approach this. Here's an example of my code that I'm doing the hard way. As you can see I'm coding in a tedious way. I only know how to grab one of the letters and convert those to one byte. I saw no examples of how to use a custom table online that even handles the length of the string. Only code that uses common encoding. If someone could give me a much easier way I'll sincerely appreciate it.

```
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim fileName As String = OfdOpenFile.FileName
    Dim fileStream As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(fileName, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Write)
    Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(fileStream)
    fileStream.Position = 2348
    If TxtHeroName.TextLength = 1 Then
        If TxtHeroName.Text = " " Then
            bw.Write(CByte(76))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "." Then
            bw.Write(CByte(175))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "A" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(186))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "B" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(187))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "C" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(188))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "D" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(189))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "E" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(190))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "F" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(191))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "G" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(192))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "H" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(193))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "I" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(194))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "J" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(195))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "K" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(196))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "L" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(197))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "M" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(198))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "N" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(199))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "O" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(200))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "P" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(201))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "Q" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(202))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "R" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(203))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "S" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(204))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "T" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(205))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "U" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(206))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "V" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(207))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "W" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(208))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "X" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(209))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "Y" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(210))
        End If
        If TxtHeroName.Text = "Z" Then
            bw.Write(CByte(211))
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the most appropriate way would be to create your own class that inherits `Encoding` and then use that in exactly the same way as you would use the classes like `ASCIIEncoding` or `UTF8Encoding`. I'm sure that you could look at the .NET Framework source code for those classes to see how they are implemented, although that will be C# rather than VB.

Here one way I can think of to create the conversion tables:

```
'A list of characters as a string.
Const chars As String = "ABC"

'A list of hexadecimal bytes as a space-delimited string.
Const bytes As String = "BA BB BC"

Dim charArray = chars.ToArray()
Dim byteArray = bytes.Split().Select(Function(s) System.Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray()

Dim bytesByChar = Enumerable.Range(0, charArray.Length).ToDictionary(Function(i) charArray(i), Function(i) byteArray(i))
Dim charsByByte = Enumerable.Range(0, byteArray.Length).ToDictionary(Function(i) byteArray(i), Function(i) charArray(i))
```

Encoding would then be a case of using a `Char` as a key into `bytesByChar` to get a `Byte` and decoding would be using a `Byte` as a key into `charsByByte` to get a `Char`.